# Editing Firefox Preferences without Firefox

Tags: java, javascript, firefox

I am trying to edit a Firefox preference in the `about:config`, `general.useragent.override`, which actually does not even exist by default, but I want my code to create it or overwrite its existing value at will without using the Firefox GUI, and instead using my Java app to edit the `prefs.js` or `user.js` files.  However, I do not see the `prefs.js` file in the folder of the profile I'm using (the default profile), nor do I see `user.js`, which I realize `user.js` isn't created by default, but even when I do manually create them, and start Firefox, the code line below:

```
user_pref("general.useragent.override","Foobar");
```

doesn't change this preference. I have also tried using the `pref` instead as below:

```
pref("general.useragent.override","Foobar");
```

But this also doesn't work. I just want a simple Java method that can edit Firefox preferences.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought Firefox kept this kind of stuff in a SQLlite database?

Comment: @DavidConrad This was updated on this Mozilla website as recently as this past September .... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences

Comment: My mistake. Are you sure you're looking in the right place? On my machine, I have a `./AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles` directory and a `./AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles` directory, and the `prefs.js` file is under the latter, not the former.

Comment: @DavidConrad Good call! user.js is working if I add it to that directory. Can you please put that in an answer so I can give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine (a Windows 7 machine), under my home directory there are:

`AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles`

and

`AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles`

directories. My profile name appears under each, but only the latter contains a `prefs.js` file. Try checking in the `Roaming` directory.